# SQL query with GROUP BY and HAVING COUNT(condition) in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, having

I have three tables: temp, product and feed.
I'll show on example:

```
select ri.id from temp ri
inner join product i on ri.id = to_char(i.val)
inner join feed f on f.product_id = i.product_id
where i.status = 'Finished'
and f.type = 'Type'
group by f.feed_id, ri.id
having COUNT(f.status = 'SUCCESS') < 1;
```

so I tried to get all ids from `temp` that have `f.type = 'Type'`. Problem is that for one `feed.feed_id` can be many rows because I could retrigger it 5 times and let's say 4 times it crashed but at 5th attempt it was `SUCCESS`, so for one `feed.feed_id` I would have 5 rows and only one would be with `f.status = SUCCESS`.

Error which I receive for this query is `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` which makes me totally confused.

`feed table`:
`feed_id`, `status`, `type`
I am interested in all `feed_id` which don't have even one `status='SUCCESS'` for `type='TYPE'`

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: The use of to_char() in the ON clause indicates your table definitions are inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't [`COUNT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions032.htm#SQLRF00624) a boolean expression in Oracle, you can use a `CASE` expression instead e.g.

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN f.status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) < 1
```

This expression returns `NULL` when the condition is false, so it will only count the rows for which the condition is true (since `COUNT` of an expression ignores `NULL` values).

Note also (as @GordonLinoff points out in the comments) that since `COUNT` cannot return a negative number, it is cleaner (and would be more efficient) to simply compare the result for equality with 0, rather than being less than 1:

```sql
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN f.status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: Why would you use `< 1` instead of `= 0`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, good point `= 0` is claner, dont know why i used `< 1` in question, my bad